# Ubuntu chrome graphic crash with developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, crash, graphic, developer-tools

Very offen I have graphic crash when I use developer tools in chrome (41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) ) ubuntu 14.04, Radeon HD 7520G AMD fglrx(proprietary drivers). When I refresh page, some little time bihevior normal, after I get problem again.
In firefox all is normal.

[image]

**UPD**
[image]